# How To Get Coordinates of the Google Maps while using rectangle query : cornerWest and cornerEast

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm currently working on a project that involves querying Google Maps for coordinates within a specified rectangular region. I intend to use the `cornerWest` and `cornerEast` parameters to define the boundaries of this rectangle.

I have tried to get the corner by this calculation,as centre current coordinates can be found by using `getLatitude()`,and `getLongitude()`.

```
final double diagonalDistance =50; // calculate diagonal distance based on your logic ;
        final double diagonalAngle =45;  //calculate diagonal angle based on your logic ;

        final double westCornerLat = cur.getLatitude() - diagonalDistance * Math.sin(diagonalAngle);
        final double westCornerLong = cur.getLongitude() - diagonalDistance * Math.cos(diagonalAngle);
        final double eastCornerLat = cur.getLatitude() + diagonalDistance * Math.sin(diagonalAngle);
        final double eastCornerLong = cur.getLongitude() + diagonalDistance * Math.cos(diagonalAngle);
```

I expected to find more detailed examples or documentation explaining how to use `cornerWest` and `cornerEast` parameters specifically for rectangle queries in Google Maps API. Ideally, I would like to retrieve coordinates within the defined rectangle to enhance the precision of my project.

Comment: Lat/lon offsets are calculated as in [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/2980/163369) or just use [com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html).  Specifcally `computeOffset(from,distance,heading).`.